# React-Native FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I'm trying to update the Android SDK version but after upgrading it from 30 to 31 it's throwing an error.

The error is:

**Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.**

Also, I have the following lines in the Logcat.

[image]

Some of my dependency versions are;

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
```

I have local notifications in the application. Because of that, I'm using an older version of the firebase.

Also, I don't have any **PendingIntent** in the project. Some of my dependencies may be using it. I tried to use couple of solutions but none of them worked.

Thanks.